# Mono for android designer exception: Android version not supported by the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mono, xamarin.android, designer

**Current versions:**

**vs**: *2010*
**jdk**: *jdk-6u39-windows-i586*
**gtk**: *gtk-sharp-2.12.26*
**sdk**: *sdk-release-23.0.2*
**ndk**: *android-ndk32-r10-windows-x86*
**xamarin studio** : *4.0.13-38*
**mono android** : *mono-android-4.8.03015*

Complete error message is:

> Xamarin.Designer.DesignerException: Android version not supported by
>   the designer

Designer capture:
[image: Main.axml]

Output message:
[image]

Installed package(android sdk manager):
[image]

Android 2.2(API 8) SDK Platform installed (Update availabe)
Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

It just found a bug similar to this : [Bug 29068](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29068).

I removed and re-added all codes, It fixes my exception.

I think it will work for you too.